# I try to implement the Android UI template

Tags: android, listview, templates

i try to use the List View from this template 
http://codecanyon.net/item/material-design-ui-android-template-app/9858746

i get the source code 
but i need the steps of how i can implement the list view in android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

you should follow the documentation of the template , as the vendor states :

> You can easily implement components from Android UI template just by
>   following our huge and well organized documentation.